# Como filtrar os resultados do Google Maps para uma região específica?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou com um sistema de rotas em que captura os dados do usuário e traça as rotas no mapa:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 
    'address': endereco + ', Brasil', 
    'region': 'BR' 
}, function (results, status) {}
```

O problema é que está retornando endereços de todo o Brasil e em alguns casos até fora dele.

Como configurar o script para procurar apenas em uma cidade em especifico? Ex: Procurar apenas localizações que estão dentro de Belo Horizonte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve utilizar a opção `componentRestrictions` e definir o filtro para o campo `administrativeArea`, documentação [aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderComponentRestrictions).

Nesse caso o seu código ficaria assim:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 
    'address': endereco,
    'region': 'BR',
    'componentRestrictions': {
        'country': 'BR',
        'administrativeArea': 'Belo Horizonte'
    }
}, function (results, status) {

}
```

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=av+afonso+pena&components=country:BR|administrative_area:BH

Comment: Eu também não conhecia essas propriedades, apaguei até o meu comentário ;) Excelente!

Comment: Entendi. E onde consigo o código dessa propriedade administrativeArea? Por exemplo, quero que seja Uberlândia...

Comment: Não é código, é apenas a abreviação do nome da cidade, pode escrever o nome completo: `'administrativeArea':'Uberlândia'` @HitchLeonardo